# Pandas time series time between events

Tags: python, pandas

How can I calculate the time (number of days) between "events" in a Pandas time series?  For example, if I have the below time series I'd like to know on each day in the series how many days have passed since the last `TRUE`

```
            event
2010-01-01  False
2010-01-02   True
2010-01-03  False
2010-01-04  False
2010-01-05   True
2010-01-06  False
```

The way I've done it seems overcomplicated, so I'm hoping for something more elegant.  Obviously a for loop iterating over the rows would work, but I'm looking for a vectorized (scalable) solution ideally.  My current attempt below:

```
date_range = pd.date_range('2010-01-01', '2010-01-06')
df = pd.DataFrame([False, True, False, False, True, False], index=date_range, columns=['event'])
event_dates = df.index[df['event']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(event_dates, index=event_dates, columns=['max_event_date'])
df = df.join(df2)
df['max_event_date'] = df['max_event_date'].cummax(axis=0, skipna=False)
df['days_since_event'] = df.index - df['max_event_date']

            event max_event_date  days_since_event
2010-01-01  False            NaT               NaT
2010-01-02   True     2010-01-02            0 days
2010-01-03  False     2010-01-02            1 days
2010-01-04  False     2010-01-02            2 days
2010-01-05   True     2010-01-05            0 days
2010-01-06  False     2010-01-05            1 days
```

Answer (score 8):

Continuing to improve on this answer, and hoping that someone comes in with 'the' pythonic way. Until then, I think this final update works best.

```
last = pd.to_datetime(np.nan)
def elapsed(row):
    if not row.event:
        return row.name - last
    else:
        global last
        last = row.name
        return row.name-last

df['elapsed'] = df.apply(elapsed,axis=1)

df
            event  elapsed
2010-01-01  False      NaT
2010-01-02   True   0 days
2010-01-03  False   1 days
2010-01-04  False   2 days
2010-01-05   True   0 days
2010-01-06  False   1 days
```

:::::::::::::

Leaving previous answers below although they are sub-optimal

:::::::::

Instead of making multiple passes through, seems easier to to just loop through the indexes

```
df['elapsed'] = 0
for i in df.index[1:]:
    if not df['event'][i]:
        df['elapsed'][i] = df['elapsed'][i-1] + 1
```

::::::::::::

Let's say 'Trues' are your event of interest.

```
trues = df[df.event==True]
trues.Dates = trues.index #need this because .diff() doesn't work on the index
trues.Elapsed = trues.Dates.diff()
```

Answer (score 3):

I run into `groupby().diff()` lately which can offer the following method:

1. Use `groupby.diff` to calculate the days to last `True` day:

   ```
   df.loc[df.index[-1]+pd.Timedelta(days=1), 'event'] = True  # add an artificial True day for interpolation
   df['last']=df.index
   df['last']=df.groupby('event')['last'].diff()
   df.loc[df['event']==False, 'last'] = None
   ```

   which gives you:

   ```
               event   last
   2010-01-01  False   NaT
   2010-01-02  True    NaT
   2010-01-03  False   NaT
   2010-01-04  False   NaT
   2010-01-05  True    3 days
   2010-01-06  False   NaT
   2010-01-07  True    2 days
   ```
2. Use `tshift()` to set correct `last` value for `True` and the `False` before:

   ```
   df['last'] = (df['last']-pd.Timedelta(days=1)).tshift(periods=-1, freq='D')
   df.loc[df['event'], ['last']] = pd.Timedelta(days=0)
   ```

   you will get:

   ```
               event   last
   2010-01-01  False   NaT
   2010-01-02  True    0 days
   2010-01-03  False   NaT
   2010-01-04  False   2 days
   2010-01-05  True    0 days
   2010-01-06  False   1 days
   2010-01-07  True    0 days
   ```
3. Lastly interpolate the NaN values linearly to get the final result

   ```
   df['last'] /= np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
   df.interpolate(method='linear', axis=0, inplace=True)
   df.drop(df.index[-1], inplace=True)  # erase the artificial row
   df['last'] *= np.timedelta64(1, 'D')

               event   last
   2010-01-01  False   NaN
   2010-01-02  True    0 days
   2010-01-03  False   1 days
   2010-01-04  False   2 days
   2010-01-05  True    0 days
   2010-01-06  False   1 days
   ```

Answer (score 3):

A one-pass solution would certainly be ideal, but here's a multi-pass solution using only (presumably) cythonized pandas functions:

```
def get_delay(ds):
    x1 = (~ds).cumsum()
    x2 = x1.where(ds, np.nan).ffill()
    return x1 - x2

date_range = pd.date_range('2010-01-01', '2010-01-06')
ds = pd.Series([False, True, False, False, True, False], index=date_range)
pd.concat([ds, get_delay(ds)], axis=1)


            Event   Last
2010-01-01  False   NaN
2010-01-02  True    0
2010-01-03  False   1
2010-01-04  False   2
2010-01-05  True    0
2010-01-06  False   1
```

And interestingly it seems to perform a little better in some quick benchmarks, possibly due to avoiding row-wise operations:

```
%%timeit -n 1000

    def get_delay(ds):
        x1 = (~ds).cumsum()
        x2 = x1.where(ds, np.nan).ffill()
        return x1 - x2

    n = 100
    events = np.random.choice([True, False], size=n)
    date_range = pd.date_range('2010-01-01', periods=n)
    df = pd.DataFrame(events, index=date_range, columns=['event'])
    get_delay(df['event'])

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.09 ms per loop
```

Versus the single loop approach with a global:

```
%%timeit -n 1000

last = pd.to_datetime(np.nan)
def elapsed(row):
    if not row.event:
        return row.name - last
    else:
        global last
        last = row.name
        return row.name-last


n = 100
events = np.random.choice([True, False], size=n)
date_range = pd.date_range('2010-01-01', periods=n)
df = pd.DataFrame(events, index=date_range, columns=['event'])
df.apply(elapsed, axis=1)

1000 loops, best of 3: 2.4 ms per loop
```

Perhaps there's some nuance in that comparison that doesn't make it fair but either way, the no-custom-functions version certainly doesn't seem to be a whole lot slower, if at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here another approach, comparing the dates with a lookup table.

---

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data=io.StringIO('''
date,event
2010-01-01,False
2010-01-02,True
2010-01-03,False
2010-01-04,False
2010-01-05,True
2010-01-06,False
''')

df = pd.read_csv( data, parse_dates=['date'] )
df.set_index( 'date', inplace=True )
print( df )

            event
date             
2010-01-01  False
2010-01-02   True
2010-01-03  False
2010-01-04  False
2010-01-05   True
2010-01-06  False
```

---

I first make a list of the dates when the event happened:

```
when_events = df[ (df['event']==True) ].index
when_events = pd.Series( when_events )
print( when_events )

0   2010-01-02
1   2010-01-05
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

And then use it to lookup the biggest date that is not bigger than my index:

```
df[ 'last' ] = df.index
df[ 'last' ] = df['last'].apply( lambda x: when_events[ when_events<=x ].max() )
df[ 'elapsed' ] = df.index.values - df[ 'last' ] 
print( df )

            event       last elapsed
date                                
2010-01-01  False        NaT     NaT
2010-01-02   True 2010-01-02  0 days
2010-01-03  False 2010-01-02  1 days
2010-01-04  False 2010-01-02  2 days
2010-01-05   True 2010-01-05  0 days
2010-01-06  False 2010-01-05  1 days
```

I am sure it can be prettier and smaller, but you get the idea.

Hope it helps!

---

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for a readable, simple solution that is perhaps not efficient on larger datasets, I just did the following. In my setting, I wanted to calculate the number of speaker utterances (turns) between topic changes in a conversation. `coder` referred to a particular research assistant (many research assistants coded each conversation, so each had their own column of 1's and 0's indicating topic changes or topic continuations). In my case, adjacent rows always differed by one time step, so I didn't need to access a datetime index -- I could just increment (and reset at topic changes) a `turns_since_last` counter on every new row (utterance/turn) in my dataset:

```
def turns_since_last_topic(coder):
    turns_since_last = 0
    coding['turns_since_last_{}'.format(coder)] = np.nan    
    for idx, row in coding.iterrows():
        if not row[coder]:
            turns_since_last += 1
        else:
            turns_since_last += 1
            coding.loc[idx, 'turns_since_last_{}'.format(coder)] = turns_since_last
            turns_since_last = 0
```