# in-group time-to event counter

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to work through the methodology for churn prediction I found [here](https://ragulpr.github.io/2016/12/22/WTTE-RNN-Hackless-churn-modeling/):

Let's say today is 1/6/2017. I have a pandas dataframe, df, that I want to add two columns to.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a', '2017-01-01', 0],
    ['a', '2017-01-02', 0],
    ['a', '2017-01-03', 0],
    ['a', '2017-01-04', 1],
    ['a', '2017-01-05', 1],
    ['b', '2017-01-01', 0],
    ['b', '2017-01-02', 1],
    ['b', '2017-01-03', 0],
    ['b', '2017-01-04', 0],
    ['b', '2017-01-05', 0]
    ]
    ,columns=['id','date','is_event']
)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

One is `time_to_next_event` and the other is `is_censored`. `time_to_next_event` will, within each id, decrease towards zero as an event gets closer in time. If no event exists before today, `time_to_next_event` will decrease in value until the end of the group.

`is_censored` is a binary flag related to this phenomenon and will indicate, within each id, the rows which have occurred between the most recent event and today. For id a, the most recent row contains the event so `is_censored` is zero for the whole group. For id b, there are three rows between the most recent event and today so each of their `is_censored` values are 1.

```
desired = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a', '2017-01-01', 0, 3, 0],
    ['a', '2017-01-02', 0, 2, 0],
    ['a', '2017-01-03', 0, 1, 0],
    ['a', '2017-01-04', 1, 0, 0],
    ['a', '2017-01-05', 1, 0, 0],
    ['b', '2017-01-01', 0, 1, 0],
    ['b', '2017-01-02', 1, 0, 0],
    ['b', '2017-01-03', 0, 3, 1],
    ['b', '2017-01-04', 0, 2, 1],
    ['b', '2017-01-05', 0, 1, 1]
    ]
    ,columns=['id','date','is_event','time_to_next_event', 'is_censored']
)
desired['date'] = pd.to_datetime(desired['date'])
```

For time_to_next_event, I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29091468/pandas-time-series-time-between-events) but had trouble getting it to fit my use case.

For is_censored, I'm stumped so far. I'm posting this question in the hopes that some benevolent Stack Overflower will take pity on me while I sleep (working in EU) and I'll take another stab at this tomorrow. Will update with anything I find. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you explain the definition of `is_censored` some more? Having trouble reconciling your definition with the contents of that column in the `desired` df. Do you mean that that column should contain the index of the row of the last seen event within that id group?

Comment: Also, just to confirm, are you missing a row for id 'b' that contains the event, given that on 2017-01-05 you're 1 day away from an event?

Comment: Hi LateCoder, thanks for that call-out. I've elaborated a bit, does it make sense now?

Comment: The `time_to_next_event` makes sense. Still not sure about `is_censored` - maybe you could give a concrete example of why 2017-01-03, 2017-01-04 and 2017-01-05 all have a value of 1? Based on the wording, it sounds like `is_censored` is supposed to identify all rows that occurred between the most recent event and today, so I would think that there should be a list of row ids in each cell, or something to that effect.

Comment: One more edit, how does that look?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the days until the next event, we can add a column that backfills the date of the next event:

```
df['next_event'] = df['date'][df['is_event'] == 1]
df['next_event'] = df.groupby('id')['next_event'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(method='bfill'))
```

We can then just subtract to get the days between the next event and each day:

```
df['next_event'] = df['next_event'].fillna(df['date'].iloc[-1] + pd.Timedelta(days=1))
df['time_to_next_event'] = (df['next_event']-df['date']).dt.days
```

To get the is_censored value for each day and each id, we can group by id, and then we can forward-fill based on the 'is_event' column for each group. Now, we just need the forward-filled values, since according to the definition above, the value of 'is_censored' should be 0 on the day of the event itself. So, we can compare the 'is_event' column to the forward-filled version of that column and set 'is_censored' to 1 each time we have a forward-filled value that wasn't in the original.

```
df['is_censored'] = (df.groupby('id')['is_event'].transform(lambda x: x.replace(0, method='ffill')) != df['is_event']).astype(int)
df = df.drop('next_event', axis=1)    

    In [343]: df
    Out[343]:
  id       date  is_event  time_to_next_event  is_censored
0  a 2017-01-01         0                   3            0
1  a 2017-01-02         0                   2            0
2  a 2017-01-03         0                   1            0
3  a 2017-01-04         1                   0            0
4  a 2017-01-05         1                   0            0
5  b 2017-01-01         0                   1            0
6  b 2017-01-02         1                   0            0
7  b 2017-01-03         0                   3            1
8  b 2017-01-04         0                   2            1
9  b 2017-01-05         0                   1            1
```

Comment: LateCoder, this is perfect. Thanks for your effort, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To generalize the method for `is_censored` to include cases where an event happens more than once within each `id`, I wrote this:

```
df['is_censored2'] = 1

max_dates = df[df['is_event'] == 1].groupby('id',as_index=False)['date'].max()
max_dates.columns = ['id','max_date']
df = pd.merge(df,max_dates,on=['id'],how='left')

df['is_censored2'][df['date'] <= df['max_date']] = 0
```

It initializes the column at 1 then grabs the max date associated with an event within each `id` and populates a 0 in `is_censored2` if there are any dates in `id` that are less than or equal to it.